# Difference between Date.parse() and .getTime()

Tags: javascript, date

What's the main difference between:

```
dt = new Date();
ms = Date.parse(dt);
```

and

```
dt = new Date();
ms = dt.getTime();
```

they have the same output, but what the difference? and which one should i use?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The first version converts a `Date` to a string and parses it, which is a pretty pointless thing to do - and in some cases could lose information, I suspect. (Imagine during a DST transition, when the clock goes back - the same local times occur twice for that hour, and I don't know offhand whether the string representation would differentiate between the two occurrences.)

The second is significantly cleaner in my view. In general, you should avoid string conversions when you don't need them - they can often lead to problems, and there's nothing in what you're trying to do which is *inherently* about a string representation.

Unless you actually *need* the `Date` elsewhere, it would be simpler to use:

```
ms = new Date().getTime()
```

Or even better, use the static [`now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) method:

```
ms = Date.now()
```

Comment: whoa, i actually don't need the _string_ because i calculate the result, thanks for answer and **+answer** about the simpler use :)

Answer (score 11):

Though it's an old post, I'll leave my answer for someone who visit here later than me.

```
dt = new Date();

// often false, occasionally true
Date.parse(dt) === dt.getTime()
```

This is because you will lose the information about **milliseconds** when you do `dt.toString()` which is internally called by `Date.parse(dt)`. At least for Chrome (63.0.3239.84) and Firfox Quantum (57.0.3), they implement the `toString()` method of Date object like this way. You can try the following example yourself.

```
dt = new Date('2018.1.1 01:01:01.001')
dt.getTime() // 1514739661001
Date.parse(dt) // 1514739661000
```

`Date.parse(dt)` equals to `dt.getTime()` only if `dt` is captured at the moment that millisecond equals 0.

Comment: As of Jan 2022, Node.js v14.18.3 is still doing this. Is there a use case where discarding the milliseconds is advantageous? Date.parse() just replaces whatever there was with zeros. It trips up the code when comparing same dates, converted back and forth...

Answer (score 3):

[Date.parse(dt)](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.9.4.2)

The parse function applies the ToString operator to its argument and interprets the resulting string as a date; it returns a number, the UTC time value corresponding to the date. The string may be interpreted as a local time, a UTC time, or a time in some other time zone, depending on the contents of the string.

[getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

Returns the numeric value corresponding to the time for the specified date according to universal time.

Answer (score 1):

Performance would be the big difference.  In the both cases, you allocate a [Date instance](http://www.javascripture.com/Date#new_Date).  In the first example, you pass the date instance into [parse()](http://www.javascripture.com/Date#parse) which expects a [String](http://www.javascripture.com/String). The JavaScript engine will call toString() on the Date which will also allocate a String for the date.  Basically, it is the same as:

```
dt = new Date();             // allocate a Date
dateString = dt.toString();  // allocate a String
ms = Date.parse(dateString); // Total: 2 allocations
```

In the second example, you are calling the [getTime()](http://www.javascripture.com/Date#getTime) method on the Date instance which will eliminate the String allocation.

```
dt = new Date();             // allocate a Date
ms = dt.getTime();           // Total: 1 allocation
```

Another option to eliminate all allocations would be to call [Date.now()](http://www.javascripture.com/Date#now):

```
ms = Date.now();             // Total: 0 allocations
```

This directly returns the time in ms without constructing the other objects.