# Issue filtering json date object using custom filter in Angular js. Date was retrieved from mongodb

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, mongodb, date

I was able to filter dates using the custom filter when the  date was  in string format.However I ran into issue while trying to filter json date object using custom filter.The json date i use was retrieved from mongodb.

Here is the format that works.It filter json date which is in string format
http://plnkr.co/edit/5IhJYSXvqa5nwd87y8kD?p=preview

but when i use json date object i am not able to filter using the dates in my custom filter(plunker showing code that does not work) because there seems to be problem filtering the json date object in my custom filter`
http://plnkr.co/edit/en36loBKQ2DAnOcbwe8v?p=preview

Is there a way to filter json dates in the custom filer i created

```js
// Code goes here

// Code goes here
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935889/difference-between-date-parse-and-gettime

var app = angular.module('tempfilter', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.sensordata = [{
    id: 'id:1',
    name: 'Rob',
    "ValidationDate": {
      "$date": "2015-02-20 18:00:05-0400"
    },
    "Temp": 42
  }, {
    id: 'id:3',
    name: 'Rob',
    "ValidationDate": {
      "$date": "2015-02-23 23:00:00-0400"
    },
    "Temp": 42
  }, {
    id: 'id:4',
    name: 'Bob',
    "ValidationDate": {
      "$date": "2015-02-23"
    },
    "Temp": 22
  }, {
    id: 'id:5',
    name: 'Bob',
    "ValidationDate": {
      "$date": "2015-02-23T17:16:14.720Z"
    },
    "Temp": 50
  }, {
    id: 'id:6',
    name: 'Don',
    "ValidationDate": {
      "$date": "2015-02-19 13:00:05-0400"
    },
    "Temp": 50
  }, {
    id: 'id:7',
    name: 'Don',
    "ValidationDate": {
      "$date": "02/18/2015 13:00:05-0400"
    },
    "Temp": 50
  }, {
    id: 'id:8',
    name: 'Don',
    "ValidationDate": {
      "$date": "02/17/2015"
    },
    "Temp": 50
  }, {
    id: 'id:9',
    name: 'Don',
    "ValidationDate": {
      "$date": "02/16/2015"
    },
    "Temp": 50
  }, {
    id: 'id:10',
    name: 'Sinclair',
    "Date": new Date(),
    "Temp": 65
  }];

  $scope.filter = {
    value: 50
  };

});

app.filter('tempo', function() {
  return function(items, field, value) {
    var filtered = [];

    var newdate = new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - value);

    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      if (new Date(item[field]) > newdate) {
        filtered.push(item);
      }
    });
    return filtered;
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="tempfilter">

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>DateFilter</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  Number of days before today
  <input type="number" ng-model="filter.value">
  <p id="demo">Showing data for last {{ filter.value }} days</p>
  Filtered list:
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="s in sensordata | tempo:'ValidationDate.$date':filter.value">{{s.id}} {{s.ValidationDate.$date|date}} {{s.name}} {{s.Temp}}
  </ul>

  Full List:
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="s in sensordata ">{{s.id}} {{s.ValidationDate.$date|date}} {{s.name}} {{s.Temp}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

`

Comment: how is this related to mongo? Or you just randomly add lots of tags?

Comment: The data extracted was from mongodb(mongolabs).  "ValidationDate": {
      "$date": "2015-02-20 18:00:05-0400"

Comment: Does your question change if you, for example, received the same data from SQL, text file or from a home-pigeon?

Comment: Problem is with  filtering the json date object instead of json string in custom filter I added mongodb as $date is part of  MongoDB Extended JSON.I got the data for dates from  mongodb. the question is specific to the filtering in angularjs for date object.